# GWT app 404 connecting to RPC servlet in hosted mode

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, http-status-code-404

We've inherited a GWT app, which works, but in hosted mode the jetty log shows a 404 when attempting to connect to the RPC servlet.

Any ideas what could cause this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this on many occasions before when firewalls are blocking the connection to localhost, could it be this? Try turning off all firewalls and see where that leads you. If it does, set GWT as trusted and that should solve the issue. On a similar note (but less likely) I've seen browser plugins such as ad blockers cause problems, and theoretically malware as well could pose issues.

Another possibility is that web.xml contains something wrong that's preventing it working properly, it may be worth checking that or swapping it out for a known working version.

Comment: Thanks, but there's no firewall configured on the boxes.

Comment: @rich, just updated my answer with a few more possibilities, are any of those any help?